# best setting of php apcu for 2000000 tags

Tags: php, apcu

In my app,I want to store 2000000 (two million) tags in [php apcu](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php) for performance.
x……x is key and values.$ar is about 2000k keys and size is about 250MB.I want to store 1 day.

```
 <?php
  $ar=array("x……x"=>"x……x",…………);
  foreach($ar as $k=>$v){
   apcu_store($k,$v);
  }
  echo ok;
 ?>
```

### This is store.php and run this.It gets no error.output"ok"

```
 <?php
  echo apcu_fetch("x……x");
 ?>
```

It gets nothing.
Please why?
I set memory limit to 700M in php.ini
Please give best apcu setting.Thanks

Comment: Did you get an error message? if you get please put its to your questions...

Comment: Let I store apcu_store("a","b");

Comment: apcu_fetch("a"); It get noting?

Comment: It is not store one.up to 2000000 tags

Comment: please why?due to large tags?

Comment: So, you assumed storing stuff in APCU will yield performance, just like that. This isn't true. Is that enough for you to give up this silly idea or you need further explanation?